# Using HTTPS or encrypt response myself

Tags: encryption, https

Currently, My site is facing many bad requests, and i want to encrypt the response in order to reduce those bad requests. 
My first idea is that let client side invokes my site's api with their unique signature which is allocated by me,

e.g. http://www.my_api/?query=aa&sign=unique_string.

And then i verify the signature, if it's valid, i encrypt the response with the signature by some encryption algorithm. Then let client side decrypt the response by its signature.

I wonder whether it is a common way?

And i've also heard about HTTPS. Can HTTPS solve my problem? If so, which is better, or please share your idea.

Comment: So you want do develop something like an access key as many web services use? better use HMAC signature instead of encryption.

Comment: No Robert, It's just a common API service which serves for Android devices. I want to reduce those unknown( which is not exactly our clients) requests. So i want to encrypt the response data. But i wonder which is the best way.

Comment: If your app can decrypt the data anybody who has decompiled your app can do this, too. Usually developer in such a situation use HTTPS (do not disable server certificate check!) and an API key. The key is embedded in the app and the app is obfuscated by a product like DexGuard.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for HTTPS.
Using HTTPS provides authentication mechanism which helps to get rid of MITM attacks. It protects you from Information Disclosure and Tampering of the data as it encrypts the communication between the client and the server (and vice versa).